# Hide path file in VS Code having Conda as interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

First of all, I started using Python with Eclipse and I didn't like it much. I looked into VS Code since so many people said it was great for Python development. The thing is like it a lot except for the fact that Eclipse showed in the terminal whatever the program I wrote said. However, VS Code also shows lots of unnecessary file paths.

Given a simple instruction such as a print I get vastly different outputs in the terminal depending if I'm using Eclipse or VS Code.

```
print(2+2)
```

This is what I get with VS Code, as you can see, the actual result I wanna see is after all those unnecessary file paths.

```
PS C:\Users\manue\Desktop\Uni\FP\Code>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\manue\Desktop\Uni\FP\Code'; & 'C:\Users\manue\miniconda3\python.exe' 'c:\Users\manue\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.10.1336267007\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '60771' '--' 'c:\Users\manue\Desktop\Uni\FP\Code\15_Oct\prueba.py'      4
```

Whereas in Eclipse I get just the 4 as I'd expect it to be. I tried modifying the launch.json file but somehow it doesn't work. I also tried with an extension called Code Runner which is super useful (only shows the actual output) but it doesn't let me do input statements. If I change the settings and let Code Runner run in the terminal it allows me to use input statements but there is a catch.

```
PS C:\Users\manue\Desktop\Uni\FP\Code\15_Oct> cd "c:\Users\manue\Desktop\Uni\FP\Code\15_Oct"
PS C:\Users\manue\Desktop\Uni\FP\Code\15_Oct> python -u "c:\Users\manue\Desktop\Uni\FP\Code\15_Oct\prueba.py"
4
```

The first output shows some file paths (I'm ok with it since it isn't overwhelming) but as I run my program more times, the gap between each line gets bigger. [See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oba4u.png)

Any suggestions would be gladly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you use conda as your virtual environment and have it installed in a specified path, that path is always shown in the command prompt when you have the environment active. If you are ok with installing the virtual environment by name, you just have the name shown in the command prompt. Im not sure if I got the question correct. If not, could ellaborate a bit further.

Comment: Please elaborate. Show examples of what you see and what you dislike about it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify "console" in the launch.json to "internalConsole":

```
"console": "internalConsole",
```

Then you can get the output at the `DEBUG CONSOLE` panel:

[image]

But, it's suggested to get used to the debug Infos in the terminal, they can let you know what exactly going on in the VSCode.